# Python-jenkins API call to reconfig job not working

Tags: python, api, jenkins, jenkins-api

I am currently using the jenkins-python API to connect to my jenkins server, get a job's info, and get a job's configuration xml all through this API successfully.  I am attempting to edit a part of that configuration xml and then push it back up to Jenkins...however, this is not working.  The API call for this exists in `reconfig_job`, but when I use the following:

`jenkinsServer.reconfig_job('jobname', 'xmlFile.xml')`

I get no output from running this, no failures, no exceptions, nothing...but when I go to look at my jenkins job, the configuration has not changed.  Since there are no messages here, not really sure what the issue is.

The XML i'm attempting to use for the new configuration should be fine, because I can use curl to push the new config XML up and that successfully updates the jenkins job.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

The `config_xml` in [`reconfig_job`](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jenkins.Jenkins.reconfig_job) is supposed to be the xml *string*, not the xml *file*.

So in your case, do:

```
with open('xmlFile.xml', 'r') as xml_file:
    config_data = xml_file.read()
jenkinsServer.reconfig_job('jobname', config_data)
```

*(Btw, check if you meant to put the string `'jobname'` vs `jobname` the variable which has the job's name.)*

Comment: Looks like I'm in the same boat when changing to that, still no output or errors and job still not updated. I can print config_data and it is the right XML with the change I want made.  Also yes, I'm passing in the string parameter of my job name.

Comment: Got it, the issue was I was using an http instead of https for my Jenkins server url.  Which didn't seem to matter for the other calls I was doing, but did for pushing up the config.  Changing this resolved it and the job configuration updates correctly now. Thank you